# StringTemplate-4: Cannot render expr property

Tags: jython, template-engine, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

According to the [StringTemplate 4 wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Templates#Templates-Attributeexpressions), I should be able to display an expr property, but I cannot.  I'm using StringTemplate4 with jython.

Here's my template file, test.st:

```
test(persons, person) ::= <<
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
    <tr><td>$person.name$</td><td>$person.age$</td></tr>
    $persons:{p|<tr><td>$p.name$</td><td>$p.age$</td></tr>}$
</table>
```

Here's my jython code.  When I try to render the template, the name and age values are not shown.

```
>>> import org.stringtemplate.v4 as st
>>> 
>>> class Person:
...     def __init__(self, name, age):
...         self.name = name
...         self.age = age
... 
>>> group = st.STGroupDir('~/template', '$', '$')
>>> tmpl = group.getInstanceOf('test')
>>> 
>>> tmpl.add('persons', [Person('jim', 25), Person('sam', 46)])
/test()
>>> tmpl.add('person', Person('bob', 55))
/test()
>>> 
>>> print tmpl.render()
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

In the interpreter, I can access the attributes in tmpl fine.

```
>>> tmpl.attributes
{person=<__main__.Person instance at 0x54>, persons=[<__main__.Person instance at 0x55>, <__main__.Person instance at 0x56>]}
>>> p = tmpl.getAttribute('person')       
>>> print p.name, p.age
bob 55
>>> for p in tmpl.getAttribute('persons'):
...     print p.name, p.age
... 
jim 25
sam 46
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?  Am I doing something wrong?  I also tried creating getName() and getAge() methods for the Person class without luck.  If I create a data aggregate I'm able to access the properties fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it would be because those properties are not public. How does Jython handle access to fields?

Comment: Those class variables are public.  In Jython private variables are prepended with two leading underscores (example: __varname).  Here's an expalanation: [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jython2/section2.html#phidvar)

Comment: ah.  I guess the debugger would tell us if you stop it in method Interpreter.getObjectProperty(). It will go into the object to try to get things out using reflection. I'm afraid I don't know jython at all so I'm not sure what the mismatch is. We can always add something into detect jython objects if you figure out what the convention is. thanks!